# JSTL tag inside a double qoute

Tags: jsp, jstl

i am using JSTL and i have a line like this

```
<cues:tr id="<c:out value="${key.id}"/>">
```

where key is a bean.

But i get this compilation error

Unterminated <cues:tr tag
        at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:923)

Answer (score 3):

Your tag `cues:tr`

```
<cues:tr id="<c:out value="${key.id}"/>">
```

is being terminated by the double quote in the embedded c:out tag

```
<c:out value="${key.id}"/>
```

just before the ${key.id ...

Try changing your tag to

```
 <cues:tr id="${key.id}">
```

Then your markup should be interpreted correctly

**Update:** In your comment you asked how *"${key.id}" is getting interpreted?*

See the [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) tutorial the section [Using Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp71322) for how it works inside a tag.

Comment: it worked. but why? why can't use c:out here? and how "${key.id}" is getting interpreted?